# Represent 'stack' of photos with XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to make a larger representation of the image like the one next to 'Camera Roll' where it shows the user that there are multiple images.

In the 'old' days you would probably have tried to show it like a stack of polaroid images however that isn't really the cool thing to do now.

I've taken a look around and can't think of anything and can't see any 3rd party libraries.

Any help would be appreciated :)

[image: camera roll]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this by simply by creating UIImageViews, altering them a bit, and then adding them to the superview. Here is an example with images called "0", "1", and "2".

```
    let buffer = 10
    for idx in 0...2 {
        let newImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.minX + self.view.frame.width/4 - CGFloat(idx*buffer/4), self.view.frame.minY + self.view.frame.height/4 + CGFloat(idx*buffer/2), 100 + CGFloat(idx*buffer/2), 100 + CGFloat(idx*buffer/2)))
        newImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        newImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        newImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        newImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        newImageView.image = UIImage(named: idx.description)
        self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
        }
    }
```

I hope this can help you with your design!